# Storing block information for a 2D generated block world

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, memory, optimization

I need to optimize my code in order to maximize the number of blocks I can render in my 2D block engine. Currently I have my blocks stored in an array of Blocks indexed by its position which holds the bitmask and blockType information. Here is the basic idea:

```
private Block[,] blocks;
private BlockType[] blockTypes;
for(int x = 0; x < blocks.Length(0); x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < blocks.Length(1); y++){
        blocks[x,y] = new Block(blockTypes[1]);
    }
}
public class Block {
    protected byte bitmask;
    public BlockType blockType;

    public Block(BlockType blockType){
        this.blockType = blockType;
    }
}
public class BlockType
{
    private string _name;
    private int _id;
    private Vector2 _textureMapPosition;
    private bool _useBitmasking;
}
```

Would I save a significant amount of memory by instead holding the index to the blockType instead of a copy?

```
private Block[,] blocks;
private BlockType[] blockTypes;
for(int x = 0; x < blocks.Length(0); x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < blocks.Length(1); y++){
        blocks[x,y] = new Block(1);
    }
}
public class Block {
    protected byte bitmask;
    public byte blockType;

    public Block(byte blockType){
        this.blockType = blockType;
    }
}
```

I actually had done this originally but found it inconvenient to have to access the index to the blockType everytime I needed to get one of the properties at a specific location. Keep in mind I am working with potentially millions of these blocks loaded into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have millions of blocks,  **yes** you would save significant memory.

To test, I set up a console program in .NET core and used visual studio diagnostic tools to trace memory usage. Here is the code:

```
  class Program
  {
      public static Block[,] blocks = new Block[10000, 10000];
      public static BlockType[] blockTypes = new BlockType[5];

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          populate();
      }

      static void populate()
      {
          for (int x = 0; x < 10000; x++)
          {
              for (int y = 0; y < 10000; y++)
              {
                  blocks[x, y] = new Block(blockTypes[1]);
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Method 1 - averaged 13 seconds with **3.8 GB** memory used.

Method 2 - averaged 12 seconds with **3.0 GB** memory used.

Both had about the same CPU loads as well.